# Google Drive upload file rest api returns 401 error

Tags: reactjs, google-api, google-drive-api

I want to store my json object to google drive.
And google authentication is working fine.
But when I am calling google drive api, it returns 401 error.

[image: Error Screenshot]

I set authentication, content-type, and content-length to api headers.
Not sure why this happen.

Comment: A 401 error is an invalid credential error. Have you made sure the authentication credentials are correct?

Comment: yes, I did. I did google auth with gapi, and I can print access token

Comment: Please edit your question and include a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  we can not help you fix issues with your code without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

[401: Invalid Credentials](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials)
Invalid authorization header. The access token you're using is either expired or invalid.

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization",
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Credentials"
  }
}
```

Suggested action: Refresh the access token using the long-lived refresh token. If this fails, direct the user through the OAuth flow, as described in [Authorizing Your App with Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth).